# Input color doesn't work in another server

Tags: jquery, html

I try to updating color in html.

```
<input type="color" id="updatingcolor_0" value="" />
```

and also jquery

```
$("input[id^='updatingcolor_']").on('input', function () {
    alert('color');
});
```

Can somebody explain why it works very well only my own localhost but it doesn't work in a customer server???

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with the small amount you've given us. Check the console for errors elsewhere, and check that the paths to included JS files are correct.

Comment: This is all front-end code. If you can see it in the browser at all your server is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following snippet you can check if it works on a server:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input[id^='updatingcolor_']").on('input', function () {
    $('#result').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<input type="color" id="updatingcolor_0" value="" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's any of that code causing the issue. It's most likely that the path to include jQuery or other files is different on the server than it is locally and therefore can't fine the required files.

If this is the issue then opening developer tools (F12 or Right Click > Inspect) in your browser will show a 404 error for the file that it's can't find. You will then have to figure out where it is and change the path.

It's always best to try and use relative paths, then as long as you keep the structure the same for local and server deployment the file will always be found.